# DATA DUMP WHATEVER IS ON usb 3-1 BUY USB ADDRESS ONLY

Tags: usb, dump

how can i retrieve data from "ANY" device 
using "ONLY" it's "USB ADDRESS" 
ergo usb 3-1
so that "WHATEVER" attaches to this port get dumped

as opposed to any other descriptors

"NOT" "NOT" /dev/etc... 
I'M NOT LOOKING FOR A THIRD PARTY SOFTWARE JUST THE NORMAL LINUX **SHORT** COMMAND LINE ANSWER

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but the answer could be usbmon via Wireshark.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't use capslocks to make your point.

Answer (score 1):

Most USB devices simply don't work that way.

Only very few USB device types (mostly input devices like mice, keyboards, joysticks etc.) can send data on the USB bus when not specifically asked for. Unless you send an appropriate request to the USB device first, most USB devices are not going to output any data.

Then there is a question of *USB endpoints*. Each USB device can have multiple endpoints; you can think of these as similar to TCP port numbers. There is always one "control" endpoint and any number of other endpoints for specific data streams. Some endpoints are input-only, others are output-only. To get meaningful data from an USB device, you need some way to identify which endpoint of a device you're connecting to.

Or if your question is about dumping the raw USB packet stream, it is normally hidden behind the Linux USB driver layer. To gain access to the raw packet stream, you'll need to mount the `debugfs` filesystem and load [the `usbmon` kernel module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt). Now you can do things like `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u` to get a dump of all USB traffic on the system, or use another bus number in place of 0 to get the traffic of a particular USB bus only. The module will also provide `/dev/usbmon*` devices for more advanced USB traffic analysis programs.

To get a more useful USB traffic dump, you can [use Wireshark to capture USB traffic.](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) Wireshark will automatically identify the various USB protocol elements and separate the data streams to/from different USB endpoints, and will allow you to separate the USB packet headers and the actual payload data from each other. You will still need the appropriate USB device type standards documents and possibly technical documentation for your particular device to actually make sense of the data, but using Wireshark will make that process much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
lsusb
```

Example of longer answer, that can show directly what is connected via the specified device:

```
sudo grep -ir "usb" /var|grep -i 'usb 3-1'|tail -n25
```

or if you need more info, look at more from this output with `tail -n50` or even with `less` instead of `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume when you say "any device" you actually mean "any block device", e.g., a USB flash drive (after all, what would it mean to dump the data from a keyboard? Or a fan?).

If you've got a reasonably modern udev running, you should have `/dev/disk/by-path`. For example, a USB flash drive plugged into a particular port on my workstation here will always be: `/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0`.

The easiest way to find out what it is on your machine is just to plug something in there and see what appears in `/dev/disk/by-path`.